# Not possible to fully disable gatekeeper

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-catalina, osx-gatekeeper

I only get my apps from brew or Mac app store. Every time a cask is updated I am met with 'Application' is downloaded from the internet open warning.

```
I have tried disabling gatekeeper
sudo spctl --master-disable

and turning off quarantine
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO

and even adding exceptions
spctl --add
```

Nothing works, can I assume it is impossible to stop this on macOS Catalina

Comment: if you have beta version then update in public release OS

Comment: No beta release in use just the original current version

Comment: check your status with this.   ' spctl --status'

Comment: assessments disabled

Comment: check your system preference general tab in security and privacy what show allow apps download  from

Comment: check 'xattr <fileName>' of the file